# Compilation error when initialising LinkedList

Tags: c++, arduino, linked-list

On Arduino, when trying to store an Objects in a LinkedList I get a compilation error.  I have the following definition:

```
    class Step {
      public:
          int DISTANCE = 0;
          long TIME = 0; 

    };
```

The loop in which I'm trying to populate the list is:

```
LinkedList<Step*> myList = LinkedList<Step*>();  

void create(int SCHRITTE, long ZEIT, int NUMBER)
{  
  for(int i=0 ; i < NUMBER ; i++)
  {
   Step* i = new Step();   //get error on this line.
   i->DISTANCE = SCHRITTE;
   i->TIME = ZEIT;
   myList.add(i);
  }
}
```

But this results in the compilation errors:

> ```
> ERROR:
> note: 'int i' previously declared here
>
>    for(int i=0 ; i < NUMBER ; i++)
>
>
> 31:10: error: redeclaration of 'Step* i'
>
>     Step* i = new Step();
> ```

Comment: When asking about an error it would make sense to provide the exact error msg.

Comment: note: 'int i' previously declared here

   for(int i=0 ; i < NUMBER ; i++)

           ^

Comment: Put it into the question and not in comments where it is difficult to read and easily missed.

Comment: No i just want create the Object name as same as the Interger variable in the loop.

Comment: Why do you need it to be the same name as the integer variable? Just make it a different name. It can still be added to the list. `Step *step = new Step(); myList.add(step);`

Comment: Ok but in the next loop i am adding the same name to the List, will it overwrite the previous one ? or just adding 2 same object in the list ?

Comment: The latter. It's a new object pointer being added to the list. The name is irrelevant as the name is not stored into the list (only the value). When you read it out again you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: And your reasoning for using `i` doesn't really make sense anyway. Aren't you adding the "same" `i` name variable to the list at the moment anyway? If adding the same name variable was really a problem then your use of `i` wouldn't solve it since it is the same name every loop right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a logic error in your doing: Here the basic commands for lists (modded to your use case):

```
LinkedList<Step*> steps  = LinkedList<Step*>();
//store step
steps.add(new Step(SCHRITTE, ZEIT ); 

// retrieve data from the list
steps.get(i)->toWhateverFunctionOrArray;

// iterate through the list 
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < steps.listsize(); i++) { 
steps.get(i)->toWhateverFunctionOrArray;
... 
}
void create(int SCHRITTE, long ZEIT, int NUMBER){  
   for(int i=0 ; i < NUMBER ; i++) { // this adds i steps all with the same SCHRITTE and ZEIT
  steps.add(new Step(SCHRITTE, ZEIT ));
  }
}
```

or if only to add one defined step

```
void createSingle(int SCHRITTE, long ZEIT){  
  steps.add(new Step(SCHRITTE, ZEIT );
}
```

I use this concept for some years in complex applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign different type of values to the same variable. For instance, in your code, in loop scope, variable i is already defined for loop process. Change the name of Step object that you are trying to assign.

Hope it helps.

Comment: lets say im changing it to Step* test = new Step(); . In the first loop it will create that obj/class and assign the variables to the obj/class, but in the next cycle of loop, will it overwrite the test obj (because the name is the same as the first one) or it will just create a another obj with the same name?

Comment: It will completely change the test variable. Because, when you are creating a new object into an initialized variable, it will lose the previous data.

Suggestion: initialize your variable on every phase of loop and store it inside a list. Probably that's the thing you want to achieve, am I right?

Comment: Yes, im getting every cycle of the loop new data and try to store it to the list. But i dont want to replace or remove the data of the previous block in the List.

Comment: Okay. Let me think about it by writing: if you do not want to lose the data you obtained in an object, you can use it like a pointer. Outside the loop, define some pointer to store your steps. Inside the loop, store your steps in it.  You can store them like:

storageOfSteps*+(i) if I did not mistake in syntax. Every step of i, each step will be stored inside the pointer. Right now I can't remember the pointers and its logic but I think your solution is in pointers or arrays. Check them out in internet.